# What is the difference between initialize and instantiate a variable?

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, instantiation

What is the difference between initialize and instantiate a variable?

I have searched through questions, I have only seen initialize variables (assign an initial value to a variable) and instantiate objects.

Comment: Maybe you are expecting more then there actually is. You can instantiate a class, i.e. you create it e.g. with `new`. And a variable can be initialized when declared. When declaring a variable of a class and you initialize it you are initializing a class with an instance.

Comment: Instantiation refers to creation of an object, usually with a name.  Initialisation is part of the process of creating an object, whether named or not,  that gives it initial state.

Comment: If this is in a question for some form of certification then just drop the program because it means that the certification has no real value.

Comment: actually, does there exist instantiate a variable?

Comment: @Peter: *"Instantiation refers to creation of an object, usually with a name."* - No, not in C++.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - I gave the typical definition from computer science.

Comment: @Peter: I doubt that the typical definition from computer science talks about the creation of "objects". That's not nearly general enough.

Comment: @ChristianHackl ; In plain English it does.  The term is a general term that predates C++.or even computing.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantiate

Comment: @Clifford: For questions about the English language, there's always https://english.stackexchange.com/. For questions about computer science, there's https://cs.stackexchange.com/. For a Stack Overflow question with the C++ tag, I reserve the right to give a C++ answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - You're thinking in the object-oriented paradigm.  The computer science definition of object is older than that, and is a collective term that includes a variable, data structure, or function that has a location in memory with a value, which may be referenced by an identifier.    That is consistent with the OP using the term "instantiate a variable" - which is not really relevant to C++ at all.

Comment: @Peter: No, I'm not thinking in the object-oriented paradigm at all. I am also well aware of anything you are explaining here, thanks, but this is a C++ question.

Comment: @ The question is also tagged with "variables", "initialization", and "instantiation" - which are terms that are not specific to C++.

Comment: @Peter: Oh come on. You know as well as me that these tags were almost certainly auto-suggested by the Stack Overflow UI, whereas C++ was the tag explicitly added by the OP. It doesn't matter anyway; if someone asks about A and B, then the question should be interpreted as a "A in the context of B" or vice versa, and not as two separate questions about A and about B. Such questions should instead be close-voted as "too broad". If the OP doesn't care about C++ but the CS definition, then the question (and the Stack Exchange site) is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The normative language specification of C++ is the ISO standard, and that document uses the word *"to instantiate"* only for **templates**. So if someone here on Stack Overflow uses *"to instantiate"* as a synonym for *"to initialise"*, then that's formally wrong.

Feel free to download the [latest (free) draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) and search the PDF for "instantiate".

Even the Stack Overflow "instantiate" tag which you've used in your question literally says:

> In the C++ language, instantiation is the process of creating a class
>   or function from a class template or function template.

So the result of an instantiation is not an object, but a class or a function created from a template. The result of initialisation, in contrast, is an object.

---

Note, however, that the case is a bit less clear with C++14 [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template). A variable template is practically both instantiated and initialised. But variable templates are a rather rare thing anyway.

Comment: @Hamed: Initialisation is British English. As a European citizen, I prefer British English.

Comment: The terms have generic meanings in computer science independent of the C++ language:  Instantiate = Create an Instance, Initialize = assign an initial value.  It is just plain English - your comment on other answers that they are wrong are mostly unfair.  C++ language standard may well only use the term in reference to templates, but that does not mean the term has no place in other contexts - the term predates the existance of C++ or templates.

Comment: @Clifford: This was not a computer science question or a language question but a C++ question. If someone specifically asks about the correct meaning of words in the context of C++ and someone gives an answer with a wrong definition that doesn't even *mention* templates, then that's a fair downvote. The words also predate computer science, and the words' ancestors predate the English language. That's not relevant here.

Comment: No, but it is (line teh C++ standard) written in English.  The term is not used because it has some specific meaning for templates, it is used because that is the verb being applied to the templates.  It could equally validly be applied elsewhare.  You are simply being so pedantic to teh point of being incorrect.

Comment: @Clifford: What's your point anyway? This is a C++ question. C++ is defined by the ISO standard. The ISO standard uses the two verbs with specific meanings. I explain the two meanings. End of story.

Comment: @ChristianHackl : simply that you have taken an unnecessarily narrow definition, and shot down other answers that reasonably broadened that view.  The OP will see the term in contexts other than specifically template instantiation, and that usage would not be incorrect, because C++ exists and depends upon the broader context of computing where the term has broader semantics.

Comment: @Clifford: That the ISO C++ definition is "unnecessarily" narrow and that other answers "reasonably" broadened that definition is your opinion, to which you are entitled.

Comment: You are now misrepresenting what I have said.  It is not the ISO standard, it is you.

Comment: As I can see your point with ISO standard, also when I search "meaning of instantiation in c++" first things that I can see is [this](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/26857/instantiate) and [this](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/cpp/instantiation). Are they completely wrong?

Comment: @Clifford "Initialize = assign an initial value" well that's another thing that doesn't work in C++. Assignment is something you do to an object that has already been initialized. There would be little point in an answer with such generic meanings, because it would be incorrect.

Comment: @juanchopanza : Had I posted an answer rather than a comment I'd have been careful to explain that.

Comment: @Hamed: I'd say they are a bit sloppy, because they use words with a different meaning than what the C++ language standard says. The first reference also looks sloppy in other parts (e.g., it implies that both C++ and Java create the same kinds of executable programs, which is wrong). If you want the precise technical meaning of something in C++, then only official ISO sources are authorative. Whether you always need the precise technical meaning is a different thing, of course. You can probably live a good life as a C++ software engineer without ever using the word "to instantiate" correctly.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Then I guess it's an example of "don't believe whatever you read in internet". Thanks.

Comment: @Hamed: Your second source also uses `using namespace std;` in what looks like global scope in a header file. This alone should warn you about its low quality! :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Uh didn't catch that... embarrassing. I blame google.